# Does constexpr in pointers make a difference

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, constant-expression

What is the difference between `constexpr int *np = nullptr` and `int const *np = nullptr`?

`np` is a constant pointer to an int that is null, in both cases. Is there any specific use of `constexpr` in context of pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to do anything with the pointer and use the result in a constant expression, then the pointer must be marked as constexpr.  The simple example is pointer arithmetic, or pointer dereferencing:

```
static constexpr int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
constexpr const int *first = arr;
constexpr const int *second = first + 1; // would fail if first wasn't constexpr
constexpr int i = *second;
```

In the above example, `second` can only be `constexpr` if `first` is. Similarly `*second` can only be a constant expression if `second` is `constexpr`

If you try to call a `constexpr` member function through a pointer and use the result as a constant expression, the pointer you call it through must itself be a constant expression

```
struct S {
    constexpr int f() const { return 1; }  
};

int main() {
    static constexpr S s{};
    const S *sp = &s;
    constexpr int i = sp->f(); // error: sp not a constant expression
}
```

If we instead say

```
constexpr const S *sp = &s;
```

then the above works works.  Please note that the above does (incorrectly) compiled and run with gcc-4.9, but not gcc-5.1

Comment: In both examples you make the mistake not to make the pointer `const`. If you use `const int *const first = arr` and `const S *const sp` it will work.

Comment: @TomaszSodzawiczny that is [incorrect](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/321c7fe64b8142ff)

Comment: thanks for checking! I tried g++ 4.9.2 - and it worked. Also it met my understanding of the standard, so didn't check further... I will look into that more.

Comment: It is weird that it worked with g++4.9, I'm sure there's a bug report about it somewhere